# (Angular 6) Should a child function return objects that it is manipulating?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services

I am not a developer by training, so it is likely that my question reveals some basic misunderstanding. I have tried searching for this topic, but am really not sure what phrases to even look for. (Is this something to do with scope? Permissions?)

I am working on an Angular 6 app. In it, I have a service with a function that calls a function from another service.

The nested function manipulates various fields on the objects that have been passed into it as parameters.

Something like this:

```
parentFunction(person:Person, scenario:CalculationScenario){
    person.age = 1
    scenario.value = 0
    this.otherService.childFunction(person, scenario)
    console.log(person.age) //logs "2"
    console.log(scenario.value) //logs "100"
}
```

And in the other service:

```
childFunction(person:Person, scenario:CalculationScenario){
    person.age = person.age + 1
    scenario.value = scenario.value + 100
    //Does not return anything
}
```

I had previously thought that in order for the values of `person.age` and `scenario.value` (within `parentFunction`) to reflect the changes made within `childFunction`, `childFunction` had to return those objects (and the `parentFunction` would have to set its "child" and "scenario" objects to be equal to what is being returned by `childFunction`).

But if I `console.log` them immediately after the call to `childFunction`, their values have in fact been changed.

Is is still preferable to have `childFunction` return "person" and "scenario" for some reason?

Again, apologies if similar discussions exist elsewhere. I'm struggling to find them as I'm not sure what terms even refer to the topic I'm asking about.

Comment: The person and scenario objects shown are passed by reference. So when childFunction adds 1 to the age of the person, it's the same person object as the one you log immediately after. Hence no update of state or a return or anything else is needed in this case.

Comment: Which is more predictable? I would suggest a functional approach where you pass something to the `childFunction` and then get something *new* back. To not know whether or not the function acts on an object in a mutable or immutable way is confusing. Try not to mix these approaches everywhere.

Comment: "To not know whether or not the function acts on an object in a mutable or immutable way is confusing."

Yes, I have indeed found this confusing (as you can tell!). Thank you for the suggestion @E.Sundin

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Shilly. "Passed by reference" is helpful terminology to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be preferable depending on the use cases of this `childFunction()`.

It's a good idea for services methods to return values to improve its reusability.

Look at the `getHeroes()` method of this service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HeroService {

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    this.messageService.add('HeroService: fetched heroes');
    return of(HEROES);
  }
}
```

Instead of changing the value of a variable declared in your service, it returns some heroes.

It's usefull because in some component, I could do something like the `getHeroes()` method does here:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero[];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
        .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }
}
```

I could easily customize the output to be used on some view by just changing the `getHeroes()` **component method**, without changing the service and being sure that any component could use the same `getHeroes()` **service method**.

---

Another good reason for having your service methods returning something, is to make easier to test them.

As shown by Balázs Takács, expecting values can be super simple to write:

```
it('should return correct sum', () => {
        expect(service.myMethod(1, 2))
            .toEqual(3);
    });
```

Comment: `getHeroes` might be a bad name for the example. OP wants to mutate something.

Comment: Yes I agree. My intention is just to give an example of how useful can be a service method that returns some value.

Comment: @andreybleme Thank you for the reply and for the suggestion to consider reusability. I suspect that will indeed be important for me here.

Comment: Good! It's a matter of choosing an approach according to your scenario. When you start to write unit tests, you may want to have yout methods returning something.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggestion to use the solution where you return a new object because in that case you can write unit test to your childFunction easily.

```js
    childFunction(person:Person,
        scenario:CalculationScenario): [Person, CalculationScenario] {
        person.age = person.age + 1
        scenario.value = scenario.value + 100
        return [person, scenario];
    }
```

---

*service.spec.ts*

```js
 it('should return updated person and scenario in an array', () => {
        const mockPerson = {age: 0};
        const mockScenario = {value: 0};

        const expectedReturnValue = [{age: 1}, {value: 100}];

        expect(service.childFunction(mockPerson, mockScenairio))
            .toEqual(expectedReturnValue);
    });
```

Furthermore I suggest you to read articles about immutability in javascript which helps a lot in things like that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @ Balázs Takács -- as well as the consideration for test writing.

Answer (score -1):

Not needed, as Person and Calculationscenario are looks like your interface/class they already have referential access, It means you can directly access age and scenario.value from your ParentFunction. Its proper way to do it.No harm or no coding standard breakdown.

Comment: Dnyaneshwar123456 thank you for the reply. You mentioned "referential access," and another user mentioned "passed by reference." This is helpful terminology that is new to me.